# RabbitMQ on docker: Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s)

Tags: windows, docker, rabbitmq, windows-10

In my java spring-boot app time to time I get this error.
Restarting docker and starting container again fixes it.

But I want to know how can I deal with it faster?
`Docker logs` do not give me anything - for example issue occurred now (14:25) but logs are old:

```
2019-02-04 13:19:41.885 [error] <0.1509.0> closing AMQP connection <0.1509.0> (172.17.0.1:55060 -> 172.17.0.2:5672 - rabbitConnectionFactory#6049c421:648):
missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s
2019-02-04 13:19:41.903 [error] <0.1517.0> closing AMQP connection <0.1517.0> (172.17.0.1:55064 -> 172.17.0.2:5672 - rabbitConnectionFactory#575a1719:1056):
missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s
PS C:\Users\user> docker logs -f rabbit-fox
```

I created this container by following command:

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name rabbit-fox -p 5672:5672 -p 8090:15672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a different port to expose 4369:4369, you can try. I dont know the reason but its worked for me. In the rabbit documentation is said about this port, you can see more in https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html